# Restore merged branch in bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

Long back I have created a pull request to merge my branch into master and it was done. I think the merged branches will not be available on Bitbucket for longer time? (Anyway, my branch is not available).

But, is there a way to recover that branch in Bitbucket?

I know how to recover it on git/sourcetree, but I want in Bitbucket to create another branch from this.

I have used this command to recover my branch to sourcetree,

```
git checkout -b <branch> <sha>
```

Comment: just push it to bitbusket

Answer (score 0):

Created a tag from last commit of my branch and created branch from that tag.